# AFNetworking, sending an NSDictionary inside an NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, afnetworking, json

I'm trying to send a nested dictionary to my server using AFNetworking.
The dictionary follows this quite simple pattern :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dico1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"value1", @"key1",
                             @"value2", @"key2",
                             @"value3", @"key3",
                             @"value4", @"key4",
                             nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dico2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"value1", @"key1",
                             dico1,     @"key2",
                             @"value3", @"key3",
                             @"value4", @"key4",
                             nil];
```

When I send **dico2** to my server with "the good old couple" NSJSONSerialization/NSURLConnection, the server receives what I expect, meaning (here the log trace) :

```
parameters =
 { key2: { key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key1: 'value1', key4: 'value4' },
   key3: 'value3',
   key1: 'value1',
   key4: 'value4' }
```

My server is written in javascript and checks the existence of **parameters.key2**. In this case, parameters.key2 is defined, so server can work with it without problem. This is the way I always did and it worked perfectly...

But now, I'm trying to send exactly the same **dico2** with AFJSONRequestOperation (with [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding]) and I receive the following :

```
parameters =
{ key1: 'value1',
  'key2[key1]': 'value1',
  'key2[key2]': 'value2',
  'key2[key3]': 'value3',
  'key2[key4]': 'value4',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4' }
```

And my server sends an error saying that **parameters.key2** is undefined !

It seems like JSON data are not encoded the same way between NSJSONSerialization/NSURLConnection and AFJSONRequestOperation.
**How can I obtain the same encoding than before with AFJSONRequestOperation ?**
Is there someone who could help on this ?

Thanks !

---

EDIT FOR MATTT:

Here is how I use AFHTTPClient : I factorized httpClient into a common method I use everywhere in my code :

```
-(NSMutableURLRequest*)formatAFJSONRequest:(NSString*)type command:(NSString*)command parameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters {


NSURL *api_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:ADDRESS, API_KEY]];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:api_url];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *JSONRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", type, command]
                                                      parameters:parameters];

JSONRequest.cachePolicy     = CACHE_POLICY_SERVER_REQUEST;
JSONRequest.timeoutInterval = TIMEOUT_SERVER_REQUEST;   

if (DEBUG_1) { NSLog(@"[%@/%@] sent to server (AFN): %@", type, command, parameters); }

return JSONRequest;
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Seb

Comment: You are getting this because you are accessing value of recursive dictionary. Try like this if you want to fetch the value :-    NSDictionary *dict=[dico2 objectForKey:@"key2"];
    NSString *str=[dict objectForKey:@"key2"];
    NSLog(@"str=%@",str);

Comment: @hussainShabbir : thanks for your answer. I understand but my problem is actually not from the "client side", but more from the server side : the JSON data that the server receives are not encoded the same way with NSJSONSerialization/NSURLConnection and AFJSONRequestOperation...

Comment: Are you using the latest version of AFNetworking?  (Either 1.x or 2.x?)

Comment: @AaronBrager: I'm using 1.3.2 version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` requests don't have HTTP bodies, so parameters are encoded as query strings. If you really need the request to be a `GET` the work around would be to create a `POST` request first and then change the method to `GET`.

This is explained in [AFNetworking's docs for `AFHTTPClient -parameterEncoding`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/parameterEncoding):

> The AFHTTPClientParameterEncoding value corresponding to how parameters are encoded into a request body **for request methods other than GET, HEAD or DELETE**. This is AFFormURLParameterEncoding by default.
>
> Warning: Some nested parameter structures, such as a keyed array of hashes containing inconsistent keys (i.e. `@{@"": @[@{@"a" : @(1)}, @{@"b" : @(2)}]}`), cannot be unambiguously represented in query strings. It is strongly recommended that an unambiguous encoding, such as `AFJSONParameterEncoding`, is used when posting complicated or nondeterministic parameter structures.